# ZeroClipboard not working , not copying

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here a simple copy link code,

```
<a class="sharelink-copy-link" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo $sharelink; ?>" href="javascript::void(0)"> Copy link</a>
```

The Function I used to copy:

```
<script>
    try{jQuery.noConflict();}catch(e){};
    jQuery(function(){
        var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementsByClassName("sharelink-copy-link"),{
            moviePath: "<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>components/com_brandize/assets/js/ZeroClipboard.swf"
        } );

        client.addEventListener('complete',function(client,text) {
            alert('copied!');
        });
    })
</script>
```

This code works for both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but when it comes to firefox,  See Image attached;
[image]

Comment: the screenshot is not useful. please provide the error message in full.

Comment: I am not sure, but try by removing one of ':', i.e. javascript:void(0)

Comment: for the screenshot, that's all it shows.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. insert below line in your html content.
href="javascript:void(0);"
In the link part of your HTML.
I hope, this would help you

Comment: The error(syntax error) is gone now, but still not working.

Comment: Let me see your code

Comment: here, take a look                                                      <a class="sharelink-copy-link" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo $sharelink; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);"> alt="Link" /> Copy link</a></li>

Comment: It simply do nothing , I think it doesn't even go in the function

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP, but the last i could suggest you that debug your code in browser(add Firebug extension in your Firefox)then you can get exact error of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the effort sir, I will.